# Java network Development

Tags: java, networking

I learned Java Swing enough for developing some not so complicated applications, such as Hotel Management, some Cafe Bar tools and so. I also made some tools for myself. Now, my brother opened a Internet And Gaming Center, and asked me if I can make some simple software for managing time counters for each PC he has, extend, reduce time and so on. So I ask which aspects I have to learn now in order to be able to do this? What do I need to upgrade my knowledge. Is this a Java Server Sockets and Client Sockets? Java Thread server?

Comment: I did a basic Google search and found [Mkahawa](http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/), why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you're trying to achieve exactly. If your will interact with the other computers then maybe you should look at a client/server architecture, and some network basic concept should help. If you only need standalone time tracking then I'd say you're pretty good to go...